# Converting array to hash with empty params

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
arr = ["dog", "cat", "eel"]
```

And I'd like to convert it into a JSON like so:

```
'{"dog": {}, "cat": {}, "eel": {} }'
```

I've tried using map like so:

```
arr.map{ |a| { a => {} } }
```

Then using .to_json, but it doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) thusly:

```
h = arr.each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h[k] = { } }
```

then you can JSONifiy `h` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative using [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
arr = ["dog", "cat", "eel"]
Hash[arr.map { |key| [key,{}] }]
# => {"dog"=>{}, "cat"=>{}, "eel"=>{}}
puts JSON.dump(Hash[arr.map { |key| [key,{}] }])
# => {"dog":{},"cat":{},"eel":{}}
```

Comment: Ah, there it is.  If there wasn't an answer using `Hash[]`, I was going to add it.

Answer (score 2):

in ruby 2.1.0

```
 a = [...]
 a.map{|k| [k,{}] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be:

```
arr = [...]
hash = {}
arr.each {|k| hash[k] = {} }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["dog", "cat", "eel"]
@hash = {}

arr.collect{|a| @hash[a] ={}}

@hash.to_json 
# "{\"dog\":{},\"cat\":{},\"eel\":{}}"
```

You are trying to initialize an empty hash to each element of array, `to_json` wont work like that

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ["dog", "cat", "eel"]

# For Hash
hash = arr.inject({}) {|h, element| h.update(element => {}) }
# => {"dog"=>{}, "cat"=>{}, "eel"=>{}}

# For JSON Hash
json_hash = arr.inject({}) {|h, element| h.update(element => {}) }.to_json
# => "{\"dog\":{},\"cat\":{},\"eel\":{}}"
```